# What arguments should be used in discard function in this geocoding example?

Tags: r, geocoding

I'm trying to geocode twitter profile locations into latitude and longitude, and was looking to use this tutorial as a guideline. https://rud.is/books/21-recipes/geocoding-locations-from-profiles-or-elsewhere.html

Once the general user information is collected, how is the discard function exactly used here? I ran their example code and got 
    Error in discard(user_info$location, `==`, "") : unused argument ("")

Followed by an error that object "coded" was not found.
What arguments are missing and how would I reach the final step of obtaining lat/long?

```
#Code from tutorial
library(rtweet)

library(ggmap)

library(tidyverse)

rstats_us <- search_tweets("#rstats", 3000)

user_info <- lookup_users(unique(rstats_us$user_id))

 discard(user_info$location, `==`, "") %>% 
 ggmap::geocode() -> coded

 coded$location <- discard(user_info$location, `==`, "")

user_info <- left_join(user_info, coded, "location")
```

Expected output would be I call the tibble I would have the row, location, and coordinates.

Error messages

```
Error in discard(user_info$location, `==`, "") : unused argument ("")
Error in tbl_vars_dispatch(x) : object 'coded' not found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want:

```
user_info$location %>% discard(. == "")
```

or

```
discard(user_info$location, ~.x == "")
```

`discard` is looking for a logical predicate or test. See `?discard` for more information.

Edit:

Here's a simple example:

```
library(purrr)
v <- c("New York", "", "San Francisco", "Chicago", "")
discard(v, ~.x == "")
```

```
[1] "New York"      "San Francisco" "Chicago"
```

Comment: Is this meant for the first use of discard? When I replaced I now get the error        > user_info$location %>% discard(. == "")
 [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
> %>% 
Error: unexpected SPECIAL in "%>%"
>   ggmap::geocode() -> coded
Error in stopifnot(is.character(location)) : 
  argument "location" is missing, with no default
>

Comment: Yes, that's the syntax for the first use of discard. Otherwise, the `coded` object doesn't get created. I added a similar example to my answer. Does that help?